# Can a smartphone transmit over the 902-928MHz bands?

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, remote-control, transmitter

I came across a remote control that uses the 902-928MHz band. Can a smartphone transmit WiFi/Bluetooth over those frequencies? If yes, is there anything special about it?

Thanks

Comment: WiFi & BT operate over the 2.4 (and 5) GHz bands don't they?

Comment: It seems like you might be better off first analyzing how the remote control is built and use that information to implement whatever it is you are thinking of.

Comment: Whats your idea of analyzing the remote control and then using it to design what I want? Any leads or thoughts you want to share?

Comment: Yes, gladly. I own a piece of SDR (Software defined radio) hardware. It has a very large tunable range (from hundreds of megahertz to a few gigahertz) and decent instantaneous bandwidth. With some hard work, you could deduce the modulation scheme of the remote control and emulate that. Still -- without going through all that trouble and financial investment, you may want to just open up the controller and see if it is using a cc1110. Then you may be able to dump the firmware, etc etc etc.

Comment: tl;dr you would first need to find out what modulation scheme the controller uses if you plan on controlling the remote device. Taking apart electronics is fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a smartphone transmit over the 902-928MHz bands?

Maybe, depends on the cellular system it is designed to interface with.

> Can a smartphone transmit WiFi/Bluetooth over those frequencies?

No, both bluetooth and most wifi implementations target the 2.4GHz band.

Sure -- you could theoretically change the physical layer to transport over a different frequency band but that would require design of new radio frequency circuitry. It is not a simple software solution.

Comment: Yes, I know how the bandwidths of BT and WiFi. Just wanted to see if there is someway to hack the android software to manipulate the builtin antenna